# Use webpack modifyVars to override ant design default.less variables in create-react-app using react app rewired

Tags: reactjs, webpack, antd

I want to modify ant design *default.less* variables in my application that has been setup using create-react-app. I did not eject, but used react-app-rewired to modify inject custom webpack configurations. I am able to override most of the variable by following the [link](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app#Customize-Theme). I have the following directory structure:

```
--App
  |--config-overrides.js
  |--src
     |--styles
        |--styles.css
        |--(maybe include a .less file to achieve the purpose)
```

*config-overrides.js*

```
  const { injectBabelPlugin } = require('react-app-rewired');                  
  const { compose } = require('react-app-rewired');                            
  const rewireLess = require('react-app-rewire-less');                              

  module.exports = function override(config, env) {                            
    config = injectBabelPlugin(
      ['import', { libraryName: 'antd', libraryDirectory: 'es', style: true }],                                              
      config,                                                                  
    );
    config = rewireLess.withLoaderOptions({
      modifyVars: {
        '@ant-prefix' : 'ant',

        '@primary-color': '#006778', //works

        '@text-color': '#505050', //works

        //Not able to inject styles this way.     
        "@{ant-prefix}-divider-vertical { height: unset; }" //doesn't work                             
      },
      javascriptEnabled: true,                                                 
    })(config, env);
```

The app won't start with above when I add the last line in `modifyVars` object. I want to be able to override the antd classes like this.

*eg:*

```
.@{ant-prefix}-btn-primary {
    &:hover,
    &:focus {
        background: @primary-color;
        color: #fff;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`modifyVars` is only used to do exactly that. Modify variables. More specifically the variables in [default.less](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/style/themes/default.less).

You can't use it to inject CSS like that. This you will have to do in your own `.css` (or `.less`) file that you import into the app with a normal `import` command. ([Import CSS in a react app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50628475/import-css-in-a-react-app))